# Water logging in the boot (stepney compartment)

Tags: hyundai, interior, water-leak, i10

I own a 2021 Hyundai Grand i10 (Sportz variant). Am the second owner (about 38000 km. when I got it). This is the second time I've found water in the boot (in the Stepney space) this monsoon. No other part of the interior including the boot carpet and walls is wet/damp at all and water is found only under the boot carpet where the spare wheel is stored. More specifically, the spare tire is water-logged with about an inch of the tire submerged.

Any idea as to what the issue could be and how it can be resolved?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Similar to your issue, but quite old - https://www.honestjohn.co.uk/forum/post/index.htm?t=89557

Comment: If the car was previously rear-ended that can cause the seams in the wheel well to lose water tightness, whereas the rear bumper (fender) could have been replaced without visible defect.

Answer (score 0):

The tailgate's rubber beadings are likely damaged. Water is accumulated at the stepney carriage because that's the lowest part of the car's boot. Water should be dripping inside the boot, trickling down to the stepney carriage. You should check your boot during the rains to observe cues for where the leakages are. Good luck.